# dot graph without labels

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a graph file to draw using "dot". I don't want to show any label for any node. I am wondering how to do this without specifying a configuration for each node since there are too many nodes in the graph.

Comment: Have you tried setting the font to nothing, or the font size to 0?

Answer (score 27):

Try inserting the following line *before* all node declarations:

```
node[label=""];
```

Of course, nodes which have their label property defined will still have their label displayed.

Also, if I remember correctly, at least one node shapes does not use the label:

```
node[shape=point]
```

Comment: I took the liberty to add a little demo to your answer. It felt a bit like cheating if I'd posted it as an answer of my own.

Comment: I rolled back because that's not what I suggested. there's a difference between specifying a label for a single node and specifying a label for all nodes.

Comment: ah, apologies. I misread the OP's requirement "any label", which I took as "a certain label" instead of "all labels".

Comment: I just tested it, and you're right: `node[label=""]` removes all labels (when placed _before_ the nodes).